# How to display Same date inserted Records in database display in single column in php codeigniter..?

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

Here is My Table table_old_memerization where I have inserted data from my from view page.T his table has 114 chapters. Each student need to finished 114 chapters. And if one student today finished 10 chapter then I want to show all records in a single row with respect today date. if tomorrow same student finished 5 chapter then, I want to show 5 records in the second column with respect to date.

Here is My Model Query:

```
public function old_surah_table($sid){
   $query=$this->db->get_where("table_old_memerization",$sid);
   return $query->result_array();
}
```

My Database Structure with Records:-

[image]

How to Display Records in View Page From Database

[image]

Currently, Show Like That :
[image]

Answer (score 0):

get records in groups using group by on record date.

```
SELECT table1.*
FROM table_old_memerization AS table1
JOIN (SELECT table2.primary_key,table2.date_time
      FROM table_old_memerization
      GROUP BY date(table2.date_time)
      AS table2
ON table1.primary_key = table2.primary_key
```

Use some date parsing methods to convert date format.

```
date("d-m-Y", strtotime($yourDateVariable));
```

or

```
$date = new DateTime($yourDateVariable);
echo $date->format('d-m-Y'); // 03-12-2018
```

Comment: But Brother I want want to change my date formate.I want to display same date records show in single column